# Alterar Hora do Commit

Tags: git

Eu gostaria de saber se é possível alterar a hora de um commit.

Situação é o seguinte, eu possuo um servidor git integrado com redmine. Quando os usuários vão subir código no commit fica com a hora local da maquina que está sempre errada, gostaria de quando o arquivo for commitado ele pegue a hora do servidor.
Eu utilizo um script para controle do repositório e ações no redmine.

Grato desde já.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize git filter-branch com um filtro para alterar o campo que você deseja: GIT_AUTHOR_DATE ou GIT_COMMITTER_DATE parecem as melhores opções pro seu caso.

Se quiser fazer mudanças no commit 129g9ebd59069c366ab22f1f97d2b648faf932e0, pode fazer algo assim:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter \
    'if [ $GIT_COMMIT = 129g9ebd59069c366ab22f1f97d2b648faf932e0]
     then
         export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="Fri Jan 2 21:38:53 2009 -0800"
         export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Sat May 19 01:01:01 2007 -0700"
     fi'
```

Comment: Bom eu gostaria que fosse de forma automática, toda vez que fosse realizado um commit a hora e data seria alterada, ficando igual ao do servidor.

Comment: O Git permite a criação de "Hooks" tanto do lado do Servidor quanto do lado do Cliente para chamar um script e fazer alguma ação quando eventos importantes acontecem, como no caso de um commit (no cliente) ou do push (no servidor).