# Alteração no log do GIT

Tags: linux, git, data, repository

Gostaria de alterar o log do meu servidor GIT utilizando um hook.

A situação é a seguinte, quando alguém da um commit e a maquina local está com a data errada, no log aparece a hora da maquina local. Gostaria que através de um hook ele alterasse a data e a hora de forma automática sincronizando com a do servidor onde está o repositório.

Comment: Você já fez essa pergunta cara http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115000/41113. Eu até tinha pesquisado um pouco pra te responder na original. Mas cheguei à conclusão de que ia ficar complicado. Minha dica do que você pode fazer é: ter um clone do seu repositório no servidor (já que você não pode alterar o repositório em si), e colocar um script hook pós-commit que dá um `cd` até esse clone no servidor e altera o horário do commit. Problema: você vai estar dando rebase no repositório, e se você tiver vários usuários do repo (vários clones), vai gerar vários conflitos quando eles foram dar update.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Na minha humilde opinião, eu não me importaria com isso. Mesmo assim, recomendo que você de uma lida nesse [artigo sobre data e hora no Git](https://alexpeattie.com/blog/working-with-dates-in-git).

Edit:

Aparentemente eu não fui claro o suficiente, tendo minha resposta negativada.
O link que recomendei ensina a utilizar `git commit --date` e `git commit -ammend --date` que são os comandos que você irá utilizar no seu hook.